# Cannot find symbol while using .repeat() method in Java (The code is working in Netbeans)

Tags: java, string, repeat

I'm solving a problem in Java and it works perfectly in Netbeans without any error message but the website's compiler where I upload my code drops me the following error:

```
Compile error:  Main.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
            String finalString = newString.repeat(n + 1);
                                          ^
  symbol:   method repeat(int)
  location: variable newString of type String
```

My code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String myString = sc.nextLine();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String finalString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
            String newString = myString.substring(n + 1, myString.length());

            finalString = newString.repeat(n + 1);

        }
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }
}
```

**Sample input:**
Hello
2

**Sample output:**
lololo

Comment: [That method of the String class was added in Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)). So if the compiler says it can't find the method then it isn't using Java 11 but an older version

Comment: Hi @OHGODSPIDERS. Thank you for the quick answer. So I just need to find another way instead of using that method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`String.repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) was added in Java 11. Presumably, the website you're uploading to uses an older JDK.

If you cannot modify/upgrade the JDK there, you could implement the same logic yourself, e.g., by using [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-) and then streaming and joining them:

```
finalString = Collections.nCopies(n + 1, newString).stream().join(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

[String.repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) has been included since Java 11 version.
Maybe the website you're using has a JDK version below 11.

Use you can always use this code for the String repetition:

```
String s = "Hello";
System.out.println(Collections.nCopies(3,s));
```

For further proceedings, I suggest you update your project [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) to the latest one in your respective IDE.